# Modernizr feature undefined when it should be true

Tags: javascript, firefox, chromium, indexeddb, modernizr

I am trying to use Modernizr to detect if a browser can use indexedDB.

In both Firefox71 and Chromium79, I'm not getting the expected result [true](https://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb) for `Modernizr.indexeddb`.

test `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Main</title>
      <script src="modernizr-custom-indexeddb.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
            switch (Modernizr.indexeddb) {
               case false: alert('false'); break;
               case undefined: alert('undefined'); break;
               case true: alert('true'); break;
            }
            switch (Modernizr.indexeddbblob) {
               case false: alert('false'); break;
               case undefined: alert('undefined'); break;
               case true: alert('true'); break;
            }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Command line config file to generate `modernizr-custom-indexeddb.js`:

```
{
  "minify": true,
  "options": [
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": [
    "test/indexeddb"
  ]
}
```

When `index.html` is loaded, Modernizr is adding the css class `indexeddb` to the `<html>` tag. If I remove the switch/alert inline script, this happens almost immediately.  The clue to the problem might be in the 'almost' -- the delay is less than one second but discernable.

In Chromium79, `Modernizr.indexeddb` is always `undefined`.
In Firefox71, `Modernizr.indexeddb` is *almost* always `undefined` (multiple reloads).
(`Modernizr.indexeddbblob` is always `undefined` in each).

In Chromium79, the css class `indexeddb-deletedatabase` is added about 6 seconds after `indexeddb` is added.

In Firefox71, the delay between the two is about 40 seconds!

My guess is that `Modernizr.indexeddb` is not getting set to `true` in time to be accessed by the switch/alert script. But perhaps I am using Modernizr incorrectly.

In [load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts), the accepted answer makes reference to the *loading* and *running* of scripts. But the time when a script is *run* is not the same as the time when a script *completes*.

There will be a point at which Modernizr returns it's `Modernizer.*` values(s). Assuming the problem is a race condition, can this moment be detected by another script? Or is the only option a *check...wait...check* solution, such as suggested in the accepted answer to [load jQuery script after JavaScript script has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881289/load-jquery-script-after-javascript-script-has-finished)?

I have tried using `setTimeout()` on an anonymous function to call the switch/alert section, which does then yield the 'correct' results. But then the question is, for how long to delay...?

Or am I looking for the wrong solution?

---

Notes.

A)
Without `setTimeout()`, both results come back `undefined`.
When using `setTimeout()` the results are coming back `true` (for `indexeddb`) followed by `undefined` (for `indexeddbblob`).
So we can infer that `undefined` means either
feature not available
OR
result not yet returned

B)
[load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts) also says: "*The relevant part of the HTML5 spec (for newer compliant browsers) is here. There is a lot written in there about async behavior. Obviously, this spec doesn't apply to older browsers (or mal-conforming browsers) whose behavior you would probably have to test to determine.*"

So it may be that the solution to this sync/async/race-condition issue (assuming that's what it is) cannot be applied to older/mal-conformant browsers. Which defeats the object of discovering if a browser can support something using a javascript-based system like Modernizr.

...so then presumably we need something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)...  turtles all the way down?

*I'm hoping for an answer which begins, "You're making things way too complicated"* :)

Comment: If you click on IndexedDB on [this page](https://modernizr.com/download?indexeddb-setclasses) it says that it's an "async detect" and clicking on show example shows the right way to use it.  (PS, you're making things way too complicated :)

Comment: Thank you, @James :) It's obvious now you point it out. My question (and the answer I shall now write) is a essay on asynchronicity in Javascript and how to solve the problems with event handlers and callbacks ;) Newbie error.